# How to play embed video on image alt attribute in Shopify?

Tags: html, shopify, shopify-template

I want to put a video instead of image in product on shopify. After few searches on google I came up with this solution:

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Product-videos-instead-of-images/td-p/465298

With some few paid themes it can actually put the embed video into the img alt and then it will display as a video.
Example: https://themes.shopify.com/themes/retina/styles/austin/preview

My question is how can I add that function to my theme?

Answer (score 0):

Now shopify changes related to 3d images, video will display with **product.media** object. If you want to list video in your theme kindly check [media](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/product-media) object properties. Also you can check recent changes in [debut](https://themes.shopify.com/themes/debut/styles/default) theme shopify.